# Xamarin Forms change text of button while wait

Tags: c#, button, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms to develop a Cross-Platform app.

I want to change the Text of the button "Do Something" to something like "Wait", while the code is processing the routine, and back to "Do Something" after the code finish to run.

The problem is: The button text only change after the code is completed.

Simple Exemple:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.Text = "Wait";

    ...some code..

    btn.Text = "Do Something";
}
```

There's some way to "force" the update of Text to "Wait" before the code finish?

Comment: The UI thread is being blocked by your code execution. You need to modify the Button text in a separate thread

Comment: Thanks for the info Sandeep!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    private async void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       btn1.Text = "Wait";

        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                //if your code requires UI then wrap it in BeginInvokeOnMainThread
                //otherwise just run your code
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    btn1.Text = $"Wait {i}";
                });
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        });

        btn1.Text = "Done";


    }
```

Comment: Thank's a lot Yuri! With a few adjustments, works perfect!

Comment: `btn1.Text = "Wait";` doesn't happen until method `Btn1_Clicked` is finished/comes to the end. I'm curious what thread is running when method `Btn1_Clicked` is executing?

Comment: Is there a way to update button text while we are in `Btn1_clicked` method. `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` returns void so we can't wait for it (await).

Comment: btn1.Text  does change before function comes to end. That was the point of this question

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 + Android 6.0. While debugging I could notice the mentioned behaviour. When I exit the Btn1_Clicked method, then the text button is updated.

Comment: Hm will try to do something like this `btn1.Text = "Wait";` // wait 10 seconds bool a = true; -- set breakpoint to bool a = true. This way maybe UI will be updated, as Invoke will be executed between btn1.text and bool a = true.

Comment: @YuriS could you repeat desired behaviour.

Comment: btn text every second changes to "Wait 1", "Wait 2" till "Wait 5" then text set to "Done" and function exits

Comment: Yes but what about first value `Wait`. Is it reflected in ui.

Comment: It works like you posted when in production. If I am debugging with visual studio, the first line of method `btn1.Text = "Wait"` does not work nor does the last. The change does not reflect in gui. It must be something with the visual studio debugger. Just try to debug it. Oh am Im using mvvm -inotifychange which invokes onchange.

Comment: When you use debugger it might stop all thread in breakpoint and then UI is not reflected. I am not sure what you are asking fro if it works "in production"

Comment: Actually your case works because execution switches threads when it comes to `await  Task.Run` (therefore the UI update). But this case doesn't work in release or debug: https://codepaste.net/coeta8. The thread in event is UI/main thread (ui thread is also main app thread) and also `change.Invoke` by INotifyChange is triggered, but not executed. So my question is now: How can UI be immediately updated in event method. I want to disable button as soon as I get to event method. Using await Task it works, but still you don't know for sure how threads will be scheduled or executed.

Comment: We know how threads will be scheduled and executed. It seems you are trying to use mvvm. Please post separate question with your code and may be I or somebody else can take a look. BTW, the link to your codepaste doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The main point is that you want to have the async operations you need to wait for to not happen on the UI-thread. Yuri's solution does this, but you could also do your async operations and then if you need to make any updates to the UI, you just need that to happen on the UI-Thread to prevent the UI from locking up.

The real problem comes from how your threads are working. If you want to see this real time, pull open the Threads debug pad in Xamarin Stud and watch the threads as you step through the code.

Let's take your code as an example:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.Text = "Wait";
    ...
```

As we enter the "Button_Clicked" event handler, we are now on the UI-Thread. How do we know? because the user clicked the button and we are here. Everything has run on the main UI thread. Whatever we do next in our code will continue to run on that thread unless the Operating System determines that it needs to manage the threads for some reason (performance, that's how the OS works etc).

If your some code does some asynchronous Task, like sending a web request call to get some data from a REST API, you need to be aware of what Thread you are on. We cannot guarantee that our web request call will run on the UI-Thread or any Thread without manually handling that. That's the benefit of our advanced Operating Systems, it handles the multi-core multi-thread processing for us.

For this reason, we want to make sure that any updates to the UI happen on the UI-Thread. The correct solution to your code would be below:

```
private async void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var btn = (Button)sender;
   btn.Text = "Wait";

   ...some code...maybe async or not (take out async above if not)

   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
   {
        btn.Text = "Do Something";
   });
}
```

This works for us because we are telling Xamarin.Forms to run that command on the Main Thread. Xamarin.Forms exposes the main UI-Thread this way. Another option would be to take the context of our UI-Thread and caching it to be used when making updates. This is something that is typically done in Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS applications.

The real way to do all of this is through Data-Bindings. Xamarin.Forms was built with the intention of being used with a Model-View-ViewModel(MVVM) pattern. Xamarin.Forms Bindings handle all of the context switches for you when you call `OnPropertyChanged`. That way you could just update the property in your ViewModel bound to your buttons text.

I hope this helps provide a better understanding of what is happening on the Thread level!

Disclosure: I work for Xamarin/Microsoft

Comment: I don't want to create a discussion here but ... 1. "Some code..." can do sync operations and that's why this question was posted. 2. In your example there is no point to wrap btn.Text="Do Something"; in BeginInvokeOnMainThread. In Btn1_Clicked you can just set text as you do it above for "Wait". 3. You said in my example everything works on UI thread.Wrong. Look at Task.Run. It is called because I made "some code..." to be async. Do you REALLY work for Xamarin? I honestly doubt.

Comment: And why you did your button handler async? I don't see any await. You are assuming that "some code" is async. What if it is not?

Comment: @YuriS I'm not trying to get into this with you. I've edited my response to fit inline with your comments. Done.

Comment: if you make "...some code." sync you will never see "Wait" till your code is complete and then immediately you will see "Do Something".

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin.forms use this way

```
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
       {
      Task.Delay(4000).Wait();
            btn.Text = "Do Something";
       });
```